# I want to modify what I receive by props

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-props

I want to modify what I receive by props with .toLocalString() but the console returns an error:

**TypeError: cases is undefined about the ligne : const test = cases.toLocalString() in Test component**

whereas if I render the props directly without modification, it works so the props is not Undefined.

This is the parent components :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [globalStats, setGlobalStats] = useState({})

  const getGlobalStats = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch("https://corona.lmao.ninja/all/")
      const data = await response.json()
      setGlobalStats(data)
      console.log(data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('getGlobalStats error: ', err, err.stack)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getGlobalStats()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test cases={globalStats.cases} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the child component :

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = ({ cases }) => {

  const renderCases = cases.toLacalString()

  return(
    <div>
      { 
        cases ? renderCases : null 
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `console.log` after fetching data in try block?

Comment: Object {updated: 1586879891667, cases: 1952086, todayCases: 28238, deaths: 122753, todayDeaths: 3135…}

updated: 1586879891667

cases: 1952086

todayCases: 28238

deaths: 122753

todayDeaths: 3135

recovered: 460737

active: 1368596

critical: 51048

casesPerOneMillion: 250

deathsPerOneMillion: 15

tests: 15466450

testsPerOneMillion: 1980.8

affectedCountries: 212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens before the component renders before the value of `cases` is actually assigned.

You are using a ternary operator like this : `cases ? renderCases : null`, but that is not enough.

I would do something like this :

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {globalStats.cases && <Test cases={globalStats.cases} />}
    </div>
  );
```

This will only render the component when the async function `getGlobalStats` has finished and updated the state.

Your child component will execute this :

```
const renderCases = cases.toLocalString()
```

On first render, and on the first render your async function is still going. Which means that cases will be undefined which will crash `toLocalString()`

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I looked for it two days ;)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what's happening, you are fetching the data that's an async task so it takes time but your `Test` component doesn't know that, it tries to access the data that's not there yet. So what you can do is place a check before accessing the data:

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = ({ cases }) => {

  // Check the condition here, also the method name is .toLocaleString()
  const renderCases = cases && cases.toLocaleString()

  return(
    <div>
      { 
        cases ? renderCases : null 
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks it works too, until now I had not understood this way of using &&, now I understood well  ;)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)